# Pip Installs not working through DockerFile

Tags: python, docker-compose, pip, anaconda, dockerfile

I'm new to Docker and Python, and I think I messed something terribly up while jumping between tutorials.
I am trying to get a python app to run in Docker. Python app uses Flask (I was following this guy's tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4T5Gnrmzjak)

The main problem is, I get the 'No module named 'flask''.

Dockerfile.txt is as so:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "./test.py" ]
```

My requirements.txt:

```
Flask==1.1.2
```

Test.py:

```
from flask import Flask
print ('Hello')
```

I run "docker-compose up" and it gives me the "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'"
Running the test.py works fine without Docker in the picture.
The pip install requirements.txt also works fine without Docker in the picture.

Anyone know what's going on?
Thank you in advance! ^^

Comment: what commands are you running?

Comment: In cmd, "docker-compose up" in my active Dockerfile's directory.

In the test.py,
from Flask import flask
print('Hello World')

trying to have it as simple as possible for now.

Comment: The Anaconda you have is irrelevant. The Docker container is a separate world. Try `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt` instead.

Comment: @zvone No difference. :(

Comment: I tried running your setup. It fails to install Flask, because there is no flask 1.2.1. It should be 1.1.2 instead.

Comment: @zvone Sorry, that was a typo when posting the question. 1.1.2 still fails for me when using Docker. I'm going to fix the typo in the question.

Comment: Well then you should explain exactly what you are running and where the error is displayed. Is it `docker build` that is showing you an error, or `docker run`? If it is in `run`, is it an error from Python of from Docker? If it is from Python, then you should look at the full stack trace and see what is in your Python files.

Comment: @zvone Okay... I may not be understanding your question as I was following the tutorial without any experience in Docker

I'm using "docker-compose up" in cmd. It runs the dockerfile with no errors.
The module not found error looks like a Python error to me.
The test.py file is 2 lines: 
from Flask import flask
print('Hello World')

Taking out the import statements and just printing allows the file to run.
Running the file without docker, also succeeds.
Running the "pip install requirements.txt" outside the docker environment also succeeds.
I'll edit the question with the details

Comment: Did you make sure to `docker build` before you did `docker run`?

Comment: Docker compose is a tool which simplifies running multiple docker containers at once and connecting them into a network. This problem is not related to networking, so you should try without docker compose. Run only `docker build .` in the directory where the dockerfile is. BTW, I am not sure whether it will find `Dockerfile.txt` or not. Usually `Dockerfile` without extension is used.